# When a new testing tool is purchased, it should be first used by whom? ISTQB Foundation Level Examination sample question

Tags: tools, istqb

The following question has appeared in several mock exams I did.

When a new testing tool is purchased, it should first be used by

1. A smaller team to establish the best way to use the tool
2. Everyone who may eventually have some use for the tool
3. Independent Test Team
4. The managers to see what projects it should be used in
5. The vendor contractor to write the initial scripts

The confusing thing is that, as the answer, some exams say that

- Small Team should use the tool first

while others say that

- everyone who may eventually have a use

What do you experts think the correct answer is?

My personal belief is that

> A testing tool, once purchased, should be used by a small team first to establish the best way to use it.

Or, should it be done before 'Purchasing' the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tool should be evaluated before purchasing it. Most tools (if not all of them, should have a trial version).

I will go with a small team should use the tool first; to some companies, they may not have a specialized small "commando" team that is tasked to evaluate a tool.

Answer (score 3):

Ofcourse the correct answer should be:

> Everyone who may eventually have some use for the tool

If I would have a company and I would have evaluated and paid for a tool. Then I would not want to hold people back in using it when they want to use it.

Employee: Can I use the new bought tool?

Test Manager: No, no, first the small team has to use it and establish best practises before you can use it.

This conversation sounds ridicules, not? Let everyone or team find their own best way of using it. If it adds value now, just freaking start using it now.

Though a team looking for a best practises and sharing this with other teams/persons using the tool might be a very good thing todo in parallel.

If ISTQB thinks otherwise they have a non practical mindset. Be sure to read the http://www.professionaltestersmanifesto.org/ in that case.

Comment: The conversation sounds ridiculous indeed. But I think that before deciding to buy a tool, a small should do a 'pilot run' to decide if the tool suits the organization. After buying, it can be made available for everyone.

Comment: @DeepikaFernando - you are right Deepika, but question clearly states "When a new testing tool is purchased". that means tool is already analyzed and purchased. so i feel Niel's answer is right. +1 for this practical answer.

Answer (score 1):

The tool should most definitely be evaluated before purchasing.

Ideally one would say that a small team should use it first and once they are comfortable and gain confidence in the tool then it should be purchased and made available for use to everyone.

BUT

In reality, this depends on several things like,

- Who decides the members of the small team?
- How do they decide who gets to be on that team?
- What if the small team okay's the tool and after purchasing it most of the other people aren't comfortable with it?
- Should everyone who would eventually use the tool be involved in the evaluation? Why?
- And there can be several other things to consider.